# How to predict components of an unknown function in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-fitting, model-fitting

I have some graphs. All of these graphs are function of two parameters (**Alpha** and **Beta**). However this function is not known. The only thing that I know is that by changing Alpha and Beta the shape of function changes but it is not clear how these two parameters affect the shape of this function.

I want to use a machine learning tool (preferably scikit-learn) to predict the components **Alpha** and **Beta** by providing an arbitrary graph. I am going to provide more details:
Lets say I have 3 graphs based on points stored in 3 text files:

```
#First graph: 1.txt
89.3131996411674    0.0                 
86.31206459803472   1.9218574062324632  
81.87220673358236   4.212444252488191   
76.41926314984194   7.090515235715248   
69.70749592038558   10.46295619504502   
4.695619238294171   42.982945242832166 

#Second graph: 2.txt
89.31085880364263   0.0                 
86.14246621045181   0.11975843148903698 
81.48739328101496   0.7686454222842645  
75.88152851199536   1.501591710302762   
69.15242620019211   4.034900351905526   
4.674145681785713   41.09359256010945

#Third graph: 3.txt
89.30979468139782   0.0                 
86.05550911873416   -0.9850540767366983 
81.20598538751082   -1.1003291465972356 
75.39779664162057   -2.714132118366186  
68.62777149709575   -1.3767373919651047   
4.653517556961358   39.28302423686896
```

Now if I plot them using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plotfile('1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1),linestyle='--',linewidth=3,color='k',label=r'$1:Alpha\/\/=20\/\/and\/\/Beta\/\/=5$')
plt.plotfile('2.txt',  delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1),linestyle='-',linewidth=3,color='m',label=r'$2:Alpha\/\/=30\/\/and\/\/Beta\/\/=0.3$',newfig=False)
plt.plotfile('3.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1),linestyle='-.', linewidth=3,color='r',label=r'$3:Alpha\/\/=40\/\/and\/\/Beta\/\/=0.2$',newfig=False)
lg=plt.legend(ncol=1, loc=2, fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel(r'$\mathrm{X}$', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Y}$', fontsize=16)
axes = plt.gca()
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=13)
plt.show()
```

The results would be:

[image: a busy cat]
Now I want to give an arbitrary graph (points) and I expect the machine learning algorithm to predict the coefficients Alpha and Beta. I need to mention that I have only provided 3 graphs here for simplicity, while in reality I have more than 1000 graphs and **all of the graphs lie between graph.1 and graph.3**.
For example If I give exactly the same points as graph.3 to the code  and ask to predict Alpha and Beta , I expect to get:

```
Alpha = 40
Beta = 0.2
```

Or if I give exactly the same points as graph.1 to the code and ask to predict Alpha and Beta , I expect to get:

```
Alpha = 20
Beta = 5
```

I do not know if machine-learning is able to do it for me or not as I do not know how exactly **Alpha** and **Beta** affect the shape of the graph. **I only know the graphs are dependent to these two components but I do not know what this function is**

I was hoping if I provide reasonable amount of graphs(as inputs) for the algorithm as the training set, the code could predict (estimate) the Alpha and Beta for an arbitrary given points (graph).

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: So, for those 1000 graphs which you want to use for machine learning training step, you know what alphas and betas are?

Answer (score 1):

From your problem explanation it is not clear whether you have alpha and beta values for each of *1000* graphs, I'm assuming you don't have, you have only values. If that is the case I'm assuming `alpha = 0.4`, and `beta = 0.2` from above are just some dummy values.

If you assume that your graph is straight line you can use linear regression to create an estimate of parameters a and b for given graph which correspond to interceptor (a in equation bellow) and coefficient (b in equation bellow). By doing so you will learn how a and b affect shape of function for given graph. In other words, you will learn what function is.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("1.txt", delimiter="\t")
x = df.x.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(x, y)
# This corresponds to a and b from equation above
print(model.coef_, model.intercept_)
```

However if your graph is not a straight line you can use polynomial regression. Let's say you think that your function is degree 2 polynomial, you would then have following equations:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.read_csv("1.txt", delimiter="\t")
x = df.x.values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2) 
X_ = poly.fit_transform(x) # Transforming into degree two polynomial
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(X_, y)
# This corresponds to a,b and c from equation above
print(model.coef_, model.intercept_)
```

You can use even higher degree polynomials if you wish, they will fit even more complex functions.

By doing all of this you will learn parameters to know for given x, what is output *y*. That is not what you described as a problem. You want to learn what *alpha* and *beta* are.

If you followed closely what I've written you might have figured out that alpha and beta are some parameters (such as a, b, c etc.), but in order to figure out their approximate value you would have to know which degree of polynomial function was used, and then to find out which one of used parameters (a, b,c, etc.) *alpha* and *beta* are.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For some reason the example code you provided wold not work. First it returns this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'. I removed x,y after "df" but still another error comes up : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '86.31206459803472   1.9218574062324632  '

Comment: I edited 1.txt, values are separated with tabs, and you have to add one line at the beginning of 1.txt, this header line should have "x\ty" -> x and y delimited with tab.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when you want to predict y for some value x (let's call it x_test), you should just write model.predict(x_test). Please accept my answer :)